# Seforim or Sources with Questions in Talmudic/Halachic learning without Answers

Tags: jewish-books

Does anyone know of particular seforim where there would be questions posed in talmudic, halachic or lomdish topics, but without answers?
I'm just wondering if there are seforim where there are chiddushim but which end up with questions, that the author hadn't as yet been able to answer. The yeshivah in my community (Yeshivah Gedolah of Lubavitch in Melbourne) publishes a booklet of chiddushim every few months where some of the heoros develop interesting questions in a sugya but the author hadn't as yet been able to figure out an answer, and he asks the readers to help him figure one out. It's enjoyable to read these and try to think of answers, so I was wondering if there are any places where there is a larger amount of this sort of thing. (Whether in Hebrew or in English.)

Comment: Kabba de'kushyasa

Comment: Also any tzarich iyun or tzarich iyun gadol from Rb Akiva Eiger

Comment: Also, the questions in Dibros Moshe

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/קבא_דקשייתא

Comment: Similar: https://hebrewbooks.org/56603

Comment: Sefer Mrafsin igra, but I believe they did answers already ...